# LDAP search multiple DNs in PHP

Tags: php, ldap

According to [these](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php#94554) [posts](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php#94555) in the *[php.net manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php)* it should be possible to supply multiple DNs for `ldap_search()`.

However, I can't get the below implementation to work:

```
$dn[] = 'ou=Red,ou=Teams,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=org';
$dn[] = 'ou=Green,ou=Teams,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=org';
$dn[] = 'ou=Blue,ou=Teams,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=org';

$query = ldap_search($conn, $dn, $filter, $attrs);
```

Everything is fine when passing through any of the individual DN strings, but supplying an array will error with message: 'No such object'.

An obvious work around for this is to loop over my DN array to fire off separate queries and push everything in to one array. I'd like to avoid having to do that, since I'm bringing back 8000+ objects in one DN *[(Paginated - Example 2)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-control-paged-result.php)* and ~300 in each of the other two.

**Is it *actually* possible to search multiple DNs?**
Perhaps special syntax (symbol/character) within the single DN string?

Comment: @dm03514 That's a link from my original question (?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search requests must contain a minimum the following parameters:

- the base object at which the search starts (no objects above the base objects are returned)
- the scope of the search: `base` is the base object itself, `one` is the base object and
  one level below the base object, `sub` is the base object and all entries below the base object.
- a filter which limits the entries returned to those entries which match the assertion in the
  filter

A list of attributes can also be supplied, though many, but not all, LDAP APIs will request all 
user attributes if none are supplied in the search request.

In the case listed, set the base object to `ou=users,dc=example,dc=com` and use an appropriate
filter. If the LDAP client must restrict the returned entries to entries that are subordinate
to `ou=red`, `ou=green`, or `ou=blue` it may be possible to use a compound extensible match filter
like `(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(|(ou:dn:=red)(ou:dn:=green)(ou:dn:=blue)))` - use the correct object
class if the data does not use `inetOrgPerson`. All LDAP-compliant servers support extensible
match filters, but non-compliant servers may not support this standard filter.

It is not possible to use multiple base objects, the `scope` parameter defines how many subordinate
levels, if any, are examined below the base object.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Comment: just checked http://www.ldapguru.info and it seems it is dead so 'see also' section is irrelevant now

Answer (score 2):

Did you see this in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php)?

> *Those arrays must be of the same size as the link identifier array since the first entries of the arrays are used for one search, the second entries are used for another, and so on.*

Basically, your `$conn` variable needs to be an array of connections equal to the size of your `$dn` array.

If you have 3 elements in your `$dn` array, you need 3 elements in your `$conn` array:

```
$ds = ldap_connect($ldapserver);

$dn[] = 'ou=Red,ou=Teams,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=org';
$dn[] = 'ou=Green,ou=Teams,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=org';
$dn[] = 'ou=Blue,ou=Teams,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=org';

// Match connection elements to count of dn elements
for($x=0, $x < count($dn), $x++)
{
    $conn[] = $ds;
}

$query = ldap_search($conn, $dn, $filter, $attrs);
```

Comment: Okay, thanks - That kind of makes sense. I wonder if it's possible to use the same `$conn` three times in an array.

Comment: You mean passing `$ds` by reference like: `$conn[] = &$ds`? I don't think that would work because all of the $conn elements would reference the same link identifier. Passing by value creates a **copy** of the link identifier into each `$conn` array element which is why that way works.